# More info on adding tabs in places (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

Hiya I am trying to learn how to figure out myself how to enter tabs where I need them, so, right now I have;

Kona Cotton: Violet Craft Designer Palette - Violet Craft FQ-1481-20$28.00 per bundle

What I need is;

Kona Cotton: Violet Craft Designer Palette - Violet Craft [TAB] FQ-1481-20[TAB]$28.00 per bundle

And the codes are all different, the only thing that wont change is the $ sign placement right next to the product code, and the product code will always start with FQ-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find what: `_FQ-` Replace with: `_\t_FQ-` (I replaced spaces with underscores, for readability)
2. Find what: `$` Replace with: `\t$`

Search Mode: Extended: This will use a true TAB character for `\t`.

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+(FQ-.+?)(?=\$)`
- Replace with: `\t$1\t`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(           # start group 1
  FQ-       # literally FQ-
  .+?       # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
)           # end group
(?=\$)      # positive lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we have a $ sign after
```

**Replacement:**

```
\t          # a tabulation
$1          # content of group 1
\t          # a tabulation
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Kona Cotton: Violet Craft Designer Palette - Violet Craft   FQ-1481-20  $28.00 per bundle
```